# How to open a cvs file where there is no content with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to extract from SAP at each transaction, every time I do a transaction I save it in a cvs file, I delete the content at each end of the transaction. 
The problem is that some transactions may not have data and I don't know in advance, that's why I delete the content at the end of each transaction so no it sticks the data from the old transaction to my Excel table.

The error is always in the same place,

.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

```
        Sub OpenCSVFile()
        '
        'Load the CSV extract
         '
         '
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
       "TEXT;" & fpath & "\" & ffilename, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
       .Name = "text"
       .FieldNames = True
       .RowNumbers = False
       .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
       .PreserveFormatting = True
       .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
       .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
       .SavePassword = False
       .SaveData = True
       .AdjustColumnWidth = True
       .RefreshPeriod = 0
       .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
       .TextFilePlatform = 850
       .TextFileStartRow = 1
       .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
       .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
       .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
       .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
       .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
       .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
       .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
       .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
       .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
       .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
       .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

      End With


      End Sub

       [script]

        Sub StartExtract()

     ' Set the sid and client to connect to
       W_System = "P10320"
    ' Run the GUI script
      RunGUIScript
    ' End the GUI session
      objSess.EndTransaction
     'effacer contenu feuille temp
      Sheets("temp").Select
      Cells.Select
      Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
     'Switch to the worksheet where the data is loaded to
      Sheets("temp").Select

      'Load the CSV file
      OpenCSVFile

 Sheets("BGSOCIAL").Select
 Columns("B:G").Select
 Selection.ClearContents
 Sheets("temp").Range("B:G").Copy
 Sheets("BGSOCIAL").Range("B:G").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 Sheets("BGSOCIAL").Select
 Range("B1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Poste bilan/compte résultat"
 Range("C1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Texte pos. bilan/cpte résultat"
 Range("D1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total période reporting"
 Range("E1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total période de comparaison"
 Range("F1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Ecart absolu"
 Range("G1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Ecart relatif"


Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\p100789\Documents\SAP\SAP GUI\text.txt"
Cells.ClearContents
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply test whether the file has any data before you begin.

```
Dim ff As Long
ff = FreeFile
Open fpath & "\" & ffilename For Input As #ff
    If EOF(ff) Then MsgBox "No Data"
Close #ff
```

Or if your file contains headers but no data

```
Dim ff As Long
ff = FreeFile
Dim dummy As String
Open fpath & "\" & ffilename For Input As #ff
    If EOF(ff) Then
        MsgBox "No Data"
    Else
        Line Input #ff, dummy 'reads the header row, if it exists
        MsgBox "No Data"
    End If
Close #ff
```

There are other ways to do this but this is the simplest

Comment: and if I don't want a "no data" message to be able to continue the transactions in a smooth way?

Comment: Yes, just you could use an `Exit Sub`  It's really about how the interaction works and who your users are.  You probably want some sort of message if there is no data.